# Copy a substring from const char* to std::string

Tags: c++

Would there be any copy function available that allows a substring to std::string?

Example -

```
const char *c = "This is a test string message";
```

I want to copy substring "test" to std::string.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a `std::string` [iterator constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) to initialize it with a substring of a C string e.g.:

```
const char *sourceString = "Hello world!";
std::string testString(sourceString + 1, sourceString + 4);
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a pointer is just another random-access iterator.

Comment: Simply beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can write one:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

std::string SubstringOfCString(const char *cstr,
    size_t start, size_t length)
{
    assert(start + length <= strlen(cstr));
    return std::string(cstr + start, length);
}
```

Comment: @Doc Brown, Great Scott, thanks! I guess we're *really* back to 1985, with C++ and all! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `std::string`'s constructor:

```
string(const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos);
```

Usage:

```
std::cout << std::string("012345", 2, 4) << std::endl;

const char* c = "This is a test string message";
std::cout << std::string(c, 10, 4) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
2345
test
```

(Edit: showcase example)

Comment: Actually, if you're using that constructor that way, you're implicitly calling `std::string(std::string("012345"), 2, 4);`, i.e. double construction (one being a temporary).

Comment: Of course you are right, but I see no problem with that (not with the question being phrased like that).

Comment: And then there's the `std::string(const char* chars, size_t chars_len)` constructor, which would be written like `std::string("012345" + 2, 4);` or `std::cout << std::string(c + 10, 4) << std::endl;`, which involves no implicit construction.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a `std::string_view` (C++17 onwards) as an alternative to `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    static const auto s{"This is a test string message"};
    std::string_view v{s + 10, 4};
    std::cout << v <<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const char *c = "This is a test string message";
std::string str(c);
str.substr(0, 4); 
const char *my_c = str.c_str(); // my_c == "This"
```

Comment: Totally wrong - `my_c` points to `"This is a test string message"`, as you can see by making this sample into a program.