# Efficiently copy a substring from const char* to std::string

Tags: c++

I'm curious about which copy method is most **efficient** for large MB substrings.

Here's a sample C++ program with many ways to copy a substring from `const char*` to `std::string` but how to determine which method is most efficient? Related to [Copy a substring from const char* to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297822/copy-a-substring-from-const-char-to-stdstring).

Could benchmark all these possible ways, but maybe there's a better method that's missing? Perhaps there are docs that indicate which ones to avoid right away since they require inefficient temp copies of data etc.,...

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W46rrx7eK)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

const char* str = "Hello World!";
const char* startOfWorld = str + 6;  // Pointing to "World!"
size_t length = 6;                   // Length of "World!"

void StoreWorldIntoString(std::string& result)
{
    result.assign(startOfWorld, length);

    // Slower methods...
    // result = std::string(startOfWorld, length);
    // result.replace(0, result.length(), startOfWorld, length);
    // result = std::string(startOfWorld, startOfWorld + length);
    // result.append(startOfWorld, length);
    // std::string fullString(str); result = fullString.substr(6, length);
    // result.insert(0, startOfWorld, length);
    // std::copy(startOfWorld, startOfWorld + length, std::back_inserter(result));
    // std::stringstream ss; ss.write(startOfWorld, length); result = ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string result;
    StoreWorldIntoString(result);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**The Winner**

Based upon the benchmarking and comments below, the most efficient method is `assign`.

[image: performance]

[Source](https://quick-bench.com/q/dRBW7BsMAqt6pUr_lvaXBbUxSNE)

Comment: You are going to have to test this. As long as the complexity for each operation is the same it all comes down to implementation. pull out your benchmarker and start doing some testing.

Comment: There's only one way to move a dozen apples from one bag to another bag: pick up a dozen apples from the first bag, then put the dozen apples into the second bag. Mission accomplished.

Comment: One thing you can do is not take in an out variable and instead return from the function so you can do things like `std::string result = GetSubString();` and take advantage of guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: I can't think of any reason that `assign` would not be as efficient as any other method. It does exactly what you want, expressed in the most concise way. Some of the methods, `append` and `insert`, do not to work on non-empty target strings, so forget about those.

Comment: The only way to determine which method is more "efficient" is to measure, in a (large) set of representative use cases.   You'll probably find (1) there is no clear answer, since all your approaches have same/similar complexity and different approaches will be more efficient in different circumstances  (2)  the result will vary in small (and possibly large) ways with compiler, standard library, compiler version, library version, optimisation settings, available memory, and a bunch of other things.

Comment: Why do you use `std::string*` ? It is highly irregular. Use `std::string StoreWorldIntoString()`. You can return objects from functions, they will not be unecessarily copied. And your string constant should be `static constexpr std::string_view str{"Hello world!"};` (try to avoid raw pointers in C++ as much as you can)

Comment: The optimizations for copying substrings will not produce significant results.  The bottleneck is searching for the start of the substring (unless you know the exact position).  You could use parallel computing or threads, but the setup and maintenance is more costly than without.  You may want to try two techniques to speed up your copying: 1) Load as much data into temporary variables, then store these variables into the destination.  2) Loop unrolling.

Comment: Why do you think any of the alternatives would be better than `assign`? What the string implementation needs to do is check, if the capacity of the backing storage is sufficient to store the contents, potentially reallocate the backing storage, copy the contents and update the member variable storing the string size. All the needed info is provided in an already evaluated form for the `assign` function. Unrelated: learn about references; passing the string as a pointer instead of a reference (`void StoreWorldIntoString(std::string& res);`) here is just bad C++ style, if null must not be passed

Comment: tactical note: Usually you aren't being paid for *most efficient*. You're being paid for *efficient enough to meet requirements*, and that's usually a lot easier to attain.

Comment: I hope you compiled your tests with compiler optimizations *enabled*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Write simple code

Use `result.assign`. That's the function for exactly this task, and therefore it is virtually guaranteed to be the fastest.

The more complexity you try to add:

- the compiler has more trouble telling what you're doing, and fails to optimize.
- the more code gets generated, which takes the CPU longer to execute
- the more bugs you have
- the more unreadable the code -> the more bugs you'll add in the future.

QuickBench lets us test this in detail, and view the assembly, so lets do that.  https://quick-bench.com/q/5jxTRcmOQ0di2rTDRAyFhUQxGKg.  My first tests were only verifying that the last byte was assigned, but a lot of the tests were cheating, and throwing off the results, so now I verify the hash of the whole result.

- `assign`, `insert`, `replace`, `append`, and the new `std::copy(startOfWorld, startOfWorld + length, result.begin())` that I added are all fastest, and basically the same as each other. (In fact, `assign`, `replace` and `insert` are all simply calling the same `_M_replace` method under the covers)
- `std::string(startOfWorld, length)` is only ~30% slower, due to the extra allocation.
- `std::string fullString(str); result = fullString.substr(6, length)` is ~90% slower, due to the extra allocation and a full copy.
- `std::string(startOfWorld, startOfWorld + length)` is ~110% slower, which is surprising to me, due to the extra allocation and copy. This is probably not statistically slower than the prior version, and was probably just an unlucky measurement.
- `std::stringstream ss; ss.write(startOfWorld, length)` is ~880% slower. streams have lots of virtual method calls, and are generally best avoided except for I/O.
- `std::copy(startOfWorld, startOfWorld + length, std::back_inserter(result))` is a whopping ~1100% slower. Each letter is doing a separate check to see if it needs to resize. This is why you should usually use `resize` and then just assign directly (which I show in the `std::copy(startOfWorld, startOfWorld + length, result.begin())` test I added)

Comment: @vengy run your own benchmark with samples of input you're expecting and check yourself and make sure to write the code in a way that the compiler cannot reasonably determine that the size/capacity of the initial string are `0` and I'd expect `assign` to win rather than `append`. The result you're seeing here is probably just the same binary for both+noise during the execution resuling in minor differences...

Comment: @fabian I discovered that several tests were cheating, and have replaced the tests and updated the findings. However, it appears that `append` is still faster, for some reason. You can view the assembly at the link in the question to affirm it's not cheating.